# How to remove a fake Badoo profile that is impersonating you

Tags: account-management

Someone I know has recently discovered that there is a fake Badoo profile with their details, which they did not open.

There is no contact (e-mail or street address) on the http://badoo.com/ page.

We even tried to log in or recover password, but it didn't work either.

Any hints?

Comment: If they didn't open it, how can you say that it's their profile?

Comment: Well for starters: their e-mail was listed there...

Comment: So you mean someone else created an account, and is impersonating your friend? That's not exactly the same as your friend having an account.

Answer (score 4):

By searching the  [Badoo Help Center](https://eu1.badoo.com/help/?attempt_no=2&q=fake+profile):

> #### How can I report a fake profile?
>
> If someone created a profile with your details, please send us a link to fake profile via [feedback form](https://eu1.badoo.com/feedback/).